# Turbinando o carousel do bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap, carousel

Para adicionar eventos próprios no `Carousel` do `bootstrap`, usa-se a função

```
$('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {

})
```

Gostaria de saber, como posso fazer com que, o texto receba ou perca `opacidade` de acordo com o elemento avô que tenha a classe `active` do `bootstrap`.

HTML

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <div class="caption-holder">
                <h2>Nossa missão é fazer o bem!</h2>
                <p>Você também pode nos ajudar</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <div class="carousel-caption">
            <div class="caption-holder">
                <h2>Se você não tem nada para doar</h2>
                <p>Doe um gesto de carinho a quem precisa</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Tentei usando os métodos `.find()` e `.parent().parent()` mas sem sucesso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não especificou como utilizou o `$.find()`. Fiz aqui e deu tudo certo.

Primeiramente é preciso ouvir um evento do tipo `slid.bs.carousel` e não do tipo `slide.bs.carousel`. Por quê?
De acordo com a documentação:

> **slide.bs.carousel** - This event fires immediately when the slide instance method is invoked.
>   **slid.bs.carousel**  - This event is fired when the carousel has completed its slide transition.

Suponho que para conseguir o que deseja, é necessário ouvir o segundo evento, não o primeiro.
**Esse vento é disparado quando o carrossel completa a transição de seus slides**, *Tradução livre*.

Então fica algo assim:

```
$(".carousel").on("slid.bs.carousel", function() {
  //lógica aqui
}
```

A lógica é a seguite: Se eu desejo alterar a opacidade do texto que está dentro da `tag <h2>`, preciso selecionar essa tag corretamente. E tem mais.. quero apenas que o item que está ativo que receba essas modificações. Então a seleção fica um pouco mais específica.
Logo, dentro da função que é disparada no fim de cada transição eu executo:

```
$(this).find(".active h2") //tenho acesso ao objeto javascript da tag H2 do item atual
```

Agora é só modificar a estrutura, nesse caso usei o `animate()` com números randomicos só pra deixar mais bonitinho mesmo.

Ficou assim a função:

```
$(".carousel").on("slid.bs.carousel", function() {
    $(this).find(".active h2").animate({
      opacity: Math.random()
    }, 1000);
});
```

Descrevendo: A cada vez que a transição de um slide acabar, vou selecionar o `h2` do item ativo no momento e animar a propriedade `opacity` para um número randômico; essa animação durará 1 segundo (1000 milisegundos).

Espero que isso possa te ajudar a alcançar o que deseja.

Execute o código de exemplo e veja essa lógica em ação. (As vezes demora para a primeira transição ocorrer por causa das dependências, mas é só aguardar)

```js
$(function() {
  $(".carousel").carousel({
    interval: 2000
  });
  $(".carousel").on("slid.bs.carousel", function() {
    $(this).find(".active h2").animate({
      opacity: Math.random()
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <div class="caption-holder">
          <h2>Nossa missão é fazer o bem!</h2>
          <p>Você também pode nos ajudar</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/400/200/" alt="..." class="img-responsive">
      <div class="carousel-caption">
        <h2>Se você não tem nada para doar</h2>
        <p>Doe um gesto de carinho a quem precisa</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    ...
  </div>
</div>
```

Um abraço, até mais.